# Limit the fixed sub div's height on scrolling towards parent div's height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At the moment the `div(.name)` that I would like to be in `position:fixed` is perambulating all over my page and divs everywhere. I don't want to put a `background` and `z-index` to all divs in the page, just not to see the fixed one, which should be limited only at its row - the header one; at some places I have a space between two rows so even if I put `z-index` and `position: relative`(playing with `max-height` as well, without any success), I see the fixed div between the rows. So what can I do so the fixed one to be scrolled only inside of its row - header and to disappear when the header disappear from the viewport. Thank you guys in advance!

```css
.name {
  margin - top: 5 %;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="row header">
  <div class="col-xl cover">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="col col-lg-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-auto name" id="nameScroll">
        Something here
      </div>
      <div class="col col-lg-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fix your CSS. Not `margin - top: 5 %;`, but `margin-top: 5%;`.

Answer (score 0):

correct me if I am wrong, but, your problem is that you want to scroll a div within a row, you may try, `overflow: auto`, over the parent div.
link of position property for some guidance as how it works -
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp